# Linked List output not showing correctly

Tags: c, linked-list

I can't figure out where is the problem in my code:

```
typedef struct list List;

struct list {
   int data;
   List* next;
};

void insert_sorted(List** head, int value);

int main() {
    List* head = NULL;

    /*
    insert_sorted(&head, 20);
    insert_sorted(&head, 10);
    insert_sorted(&head, 5);
    */

    insert_sorted(&head, 3);
    insert_sorted(&head, 2);
    insert_sorted(&head, 40);
    insert_sorted(&head, 10);
    //insert_sorted(&head, 40);

    List* temp = head;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d\t", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}

void insert_sorted(List** head, int value) {
    List* temp = NULL;
    List* node = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));

    node->data = value;
    node->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL || (*head)->data >= value) {
        node->next = *head;
        *head = node;
    } else {
        temp = *head;
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            if (temp->data < value && (temp->next)->data > value) {
                node->next = temp->next;
                temp->next = node;
            } else
                temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = node;
    }
}
```

**1:**

Run the code and see results. (Running and running...) after sorting data it is repeating some values forever.

**2:**

Go to

```
  //insert_sorted(&head, 40);
```

this line an remove comment symbols.
Run the code and mark the result.(Time limit exceeded)

**3:**
Find this and remove comments:

```
   /*
insert_sorted(&head, 20);

insert_sorted(&head, 10);

insert_sorted(&head, 5);

*/
```

Run and see results; (Again some problems)

**Finally:**
Remove all comments symbols and run it, this time it is working without any error but not as expected (List is not sorted correctly);

But why this is happening? Any help will be appreciated, and I am not at home at this but a learner.

Comment: Your `void insert_sorted(List** head, int value)`function is doing too much work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `void insert_sorted(List** head, int value)` function is doing too much work.

---

```
void insert_sorted(List** head, int value) {

    List* node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    node->data = value;

    for( ; *head ; head = &(*head)->next) {
          if ((*head)->data > value) break; // we should insert before *head
    }

    // When we get here *head points to the pointer that needs to get node's value
    // This can either be the original head (as supplied as argument tothe function)
    // or some of the -> next pointers, or even the last ->next pointer.
node->next = *head;
*head = node;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and this one is perfectly working as I expected, I mean no more errors and sorting the list correctly!

Comment: Now I am gonna think about this logic and trying to get it with a while loop!

Comment: Why? There is no need for a while loop.

Comment: The `for` loop is syntactic sugar for a `while` loop of special structure.

Comment: @wildplasser yeah! I don't need while as for is the perfect one. :)

Comment: The solution is very insightful; it seems to be naturally obtainable from a recursive implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be fixed as follows. If the node is inserted in the middle, the function can return and does not need to append the value at the end.

```
void insert_sorted(List** head, int value) {
    List* temp = NULL;
    List* node = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));

    node->data = value;
    node->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL || (*head)->data >= value) { // <-- fix
        node->next = *head;
        *head = node;
    }
    else {
        temp = *head;
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            if ( (temp->next)->data > value ) {
                node->next = temp->next;
                temp->next = node;
                return; // <-- fix
            }
            else
                temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = node;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, errors are fixed but the list was not sorted correctly

Comment: That's awesome! Working perfectly.

Comment: Well thanks, but the answer by wildplasser is more insightful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sometimes inserted value twice (when value was not placed at the end of the list). This should fix the problem:

```
while(temp->next != NULL)
{
    if(temp->data < value && (temp->next)->data > value)
    {
        node->next = temp->next;
        temp->next = node;
        break;
    }
    else
        temp = temp->next;
}

if(temp->next == NULL)
    temp->next = node;
```